# Completar valores em coluna baseado em condição e valor em outra coluna

Tags: dplyr

Estou tentando há um tempo resolver isso, mas não deu certo.
Tenho essa tabela abaixo. O que quero é que a coluna inchikey seja completada de acordo com a coluna "cid_pub_chem". Se vcs repararem, nas linhas 1 e 2, temos o valor de 31253 para a coluna "cid_pub_chem" e valores para a coluna "inchikey" mas nas linhas 5 e 6 eu tenho o mesmo valor de "cid_pub_chem", porém a coluna "inchikey" está com NA. Deve ser muito simples resolver isso, mas não teve jeito...

```
abc = structure(
  list(cid_pub_chem = c("31253", "31253", "6654", "11040762", "31253", "31253"), 
       inchikey = c("UAHWPYUMFXYFJY-UHFFFAOYSA-N", "UAHWPYUMFXYFJY-UHFFFAOYSA-N", "GRWFGVWFFZKLTI-UHFFFAOYSA-N", "WPOQYXKDKVBMSB-UHFFFAOYSA-N", NA, NA), 
       height = c("37740", "25556", "39861", "51715", "26048", "52332")), 
  row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
  class = "data.frame")
```

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda. Postei umas perguntas no stackoverflow em inglês (não sabia da existência desse), mas faz uns bons meses e eu esqueci como formatar melhor o código (aliás, como faz isso?). Desculpem...

Answer (score 0):

Um das formas de fazer isso é construir um "dicionário" ou "gabarito" com os valores que você quer unir e então realizar uma união.

O código para criar o gabarito pode ser algo assim:

```
library(tidyverse)
valores <- abc %>% 
  filter(!is.na(inchikey)) %>% 
  select(cid_pub_chem, inchikey) %>% 
  unique()
```

E então podemos remover a coluna com as informações erradas e repreencher ela usando o gabarito que acabamos de criar.

```
abc %>% 
  select(-inchikey) %>% 
  left_join(valores, "cid_pub_chem")
#>   cid_pub_chem height                    inchikey
#> 1        31253  37740 UAHWPYUMFXYFJY-UHFFFAOYSA-N
#> 2        31253  25556 UAHWPYUMFXYFJY-UHFFFAOYSA-N
#> 3         6654  39861 GRWFGVWFFZKLTI-UHFFFAOYSA-N
#> 4     11040762  51715 WPOQYXKDKVBMSB-UHFFFAOYSA-N
#> 5        31253  26048 UAHWPYUMFXYFJY-UHFFFAOYSA-N
#> 6        31253  52332 UAHWPYUMFXYFJY-UHFFFAOYSA-N
```